# python-tk have unmet dependencies

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit, ubuntu-14.10

I am trying to install python-tk on Ubuntu 14.10 with python 2.7. but it throws following dependency error. please help me to resolve this. I tried many ways but couldn't solve it.

```
python-tk : Depends: blt (>= 2.4z-4.1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: tcl8.5 (>= 8.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: tk8.5 (>= 8.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
```

Answer (score 2):

First update the Package Index.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Build dependances before installing `python-tk`.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-tk
```

Then install `python-tk` package:

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

Comment: thanks for the immediate response.  I tried that but it didn't workout for me. still same unmet dependency error.

Comment: ok when I hit sudo apt-get update. i got one fail. Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file.

Comment: I cleared that error. But still same unmet dependencies when I hit. sudo apt-get install python-tk

Comment: @vinod The file is under `http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-stdlib-extensions/`.Check `/etc/apt/sources.list` it should contain `deb http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main`.

Comment: thank you. I got it. every time I hit sudo apt-get update, it use to throw that binary i386 packages download fail. I was ignoring that. I managed to solve it. later I installed blt, tcl, tk which were unmet dependencies. using command `sudo apt-get install tcl`. later I installed python-tk as well. Thank you @Rawly